# Fiat 500e 2017 charger

Tags: charging, electric-vehicle, battery-charger, fiat, charger

i just owned a Fiat 500e 2017 sport package... i wanted to make sure that the charger that come with it is the real original one and not imitative, as i saw charger with different style, how i can know? And is it an issue to worry about??, one more question I’m wondering about is the charging issue that is it ok to charge my car frequently? Like if its 50% 70%, no matter the percentage or it could damage the battery as in the case with charging the mobile for example?? Please help

**Note:here is a picture for the charger i have.

[image: the charger came with the car is it original?]

Comment: It doesn't *look* like an original Fiat charger. Compare it to [this one on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2013-2018-FIAT-500E-ELECTRIC-CAR-CHARGER-120-V-60-HZ-12A-WORKS-ALL-EV-VEHICLE/223904046661?fits=Make%3AFiat&hash=item3421b89e45:g:IlcAAOSwW4hcc2-o).

Comment:  is that normal? I mean does it damage the car battery?

Comment: I really don't know. I don't have much experience with e-vehicles, so cannot speak authoritatively.

Answer (score 1):

It looks different from my charger.

But No, there is no way these chargers damage your battery, as they are in fact not chargers. The actual charger is on-board of the car.

These ‘chargers’ are more safety devices that inform the onboard charger of the status and max current to draw via the CP pin. In some cases they do a few more checks. When all is OK it activates a relay to switch the line voltage to the car.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the Fiat "charger" that comes with the car. It is an aftermarket substitute.

We had a 500e for three years, leased new, and just plugged it in without regard to its state of charge. During our ownership, the battery didn't degrade.